# I cannot write text to a text file

Tags: c#, text-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The file is being used by another process, I must close it? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698879/the-file-is-being-used-by-another-process-i-must-close-it-how)

I'm not sure why is that but I cannot write some data into text file. I am doing like so:

```
    private void CreateLastOpenFile()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        }

        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            FileStream newFile = File.Create(file);
            newFile.Close();
        }

        using (StreamWriter lastOpenedFile = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            lastOpenedFile.WriteLine(filePath);
        }
    }
```

Am I doing this correctly?Should I be checking if directory exists? If file exists? What's the proper way? I was using examples from MSDN but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: confirm that you're using file/filePath as expected. It seems like you've got them backwards..

Comment: look at the answers in thread you already started - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698879/the-file-is-being-used-by-another-process-i-must-close-it-how/8698914#8698914

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather do:

```
String p = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
if (!Directory.Exists(p))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(p);
}

FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    ...
    writer.Flush();
}
```

This creates a new file if it doesn't exist.

`using` automatically calls `Dispose` on the writer, which in turn calls `Close`, which closes both writer and the underlying stream.

Comment: Would it also create the directory needed?

Comment: No. I've updated my answer so that the directory is created if it does not exist. Please note that in my sample, the `fileName` variable must contain path and file name like `C:\Temp\TestFile.txt`. It will check for and create `C:\Temp` and the write to the file `TestFile.txt`.

Comment: Ok, worth an answer points. One more thing though. I am not familiar with Flush, should that be recommended?

Comment: Flush just empty memory buffer to disk, it ensure that you don't have data which are not written on the file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to create the file, StreamWriter will do it for you. But you need to ensure the directory exists, like you do.

You can also use [File.OpenText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext.aspx).